# Can Trogdor please burninate the [must-have] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tags

Found another [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) today [must-have](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/must-have)

I call upon the mighty [image: www.bebo.com/c/photos/albums?ProfilePhoto=Y&MemberId=4866542579] and hope that he does what he does best.

Comment: Just curious, what type of questions were tagged that way? Couldn't find any...

Answer (score 3):

Few questions with [must-have](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/must-have) have been stripped of that tag, the tag will be removed by system automatically.